# Longest length of valid parenthesis problem

Tags: string

I got stuck on this problem of finding the length of the longest valid parenthesis substring which either contains '(' or ')' . Actually there are many methods to solve this problem but i tried to go with finding the longest common substring (LCS) of the two strings..

I am getting the runtime error....

> Line 1061: Char 9: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x7ffd2d443260 overflowed to 0x7ffd2d44325f (basic_string.h)
>   SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:1070:9

Please check what is wrong in this....

```
class Solution {
public:
    int LCS(string s1,string s2)
    {
        int m = s1.length();
        int n = s2.length();

        int dp[m+1][n+1];
        memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
        for(int i=0;i<=m;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=n;j++)
                dp[i][j] = 0;
        }
        int res = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<=m;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=n;j++)
            {
                if(i==j)
                    dp[i][j] = 0;
                else if(s1[i-1]==s2[j-1]){
                    dp[i][j] = 1 + dp[i-1][j-1];
                    res = max(res,dp[i][j]);
                }
                else
                    dp[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    int longestValidParentheses(string s) {
        // here we can find the longest LCS..
        if(s.length()==0 || s.length()==1)
            return 0;
         string str = "";
    for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(s[i]==')')
        str += '(';
        else if(s[i]=='(')
        str += ')';
    }

        int res = LCS(s,str);
        return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you please share the link of the original problem statement for more info? Thanks!